# No spaces when mapping every character of a string (ReactJS)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, split, mapping

I have been trying to put some animation on a title.. (using **ReactJs**)

The issue I have is that my Array.map() won't display my spaces from my string:

*Prop 'title' = "Header Right Here!!"*

```js
const TitleAnimation = ({title}) => {
    const titleArray = title.split("");
    console.log(titleArray);
    // logs all characters in an array, including spaces

    return (
        <Wrapper className="text-6xl">
            {titleArray.map((character, index) => {
                return (
                    <span key={index}>{character}</span>
                )
            })}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

Instead of having multiple spans returning "Header Right Here", it returns "HeaderRightHere"

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White spaces are collapsed by default in spans. You can use the CSS property `white-space` with the value `pre` in order for your span to preserve the spaces.

```
span {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

(You might or might not want to set that globally)

You can find more details about the `white-space` property here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following code

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const title = 'Header Right Here!!';
  const titleArray = title.split(' ');
  const renderTitle = () => {
    return titleArray.map((title, index) => {
      return (
        <span>
          {title}
          {` `}
        </span>
      );
    });
  };
  return <div>{renderTitle()}</div>;
};
export default App;
```

Note : Each element in the array is wrapped in a span